# How to add Slack message button to open direct chat with a user?

Tags: slack, slack-api, botkit

I have a Slack bot that needs to return a message that includes list of Slack users and a button to direct message each user.

I want the engagement experience to stay consistent for the user.  If the user is interacting with the bot via a desktop Slack app then I want the user to stay within the app (not to be taken away to the web client -- where they likely aren't authenticated).

Something like:

```
Results:

User A - click link to view User A's profile in Slack
[Message] - click button to open direct message with user A

User B - click link to view User B's profile in Slack
[Message] - click button to open direct message with user B
```

I'm stuck on a couple of issues:

1. How to link to a user's profile because I don't know if they are using the Slack app or Slack web (thus how to decide between showing `slack://user?team=&id=..` or `domain.slack.com/team/{id}` approach?  This is assuming I use either the `title_link` or `author_link` property.
2. How to create a message button that will open a direct message to a user (and even better open it and pre-populate a message)? I've currently been playing with a link action but have not had any luck.

I imagine I could workaround it by having the bot send the DM and then @mention the original user.  Not great from the UX perspective.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to comments from Adil and Erik I think I have the *best* possible solution.  I ended up crafting a message attachment for each result as follows:

```
    {
        "fallback": `${user['name']} likes pizza`,
        "text": `<@${user['uid']}>`,
        "actions": [
          {
            "type": "button",
            "text": "View Pizza Profile",
            "url": url(`/directory/${user['id']}`),
            "style": "primary"
          },
          {
            "type": "button",
            "text": "Order Pizza",
            "url": `https://slack.com/app_redirect?channel=${user['uid']}`
          }
        ]
    }
```

This solution provides:

- Text field which includes an @mention to the user (clicking it brings up the profile in the browser or native).  It uses the text as the message header (and drops the author and title fields).
- Link action button to open a direct message chat via `app_redirect`

There are a couple of serious limitations:

1. For native, the direct message link causes a browser to open and then (if the user decides) redirects back to the app.
2. The user MUST be using a browser window that is already authenticated to the same workspace as the native client (this is a huge problem for UX as many individuals have multiple workspaces open, in which case the redirect fails with a non-obvious error message).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding to Adil's great answer about linking to a user profile

Here is how to provide a link to open a direct message between the current and another user:

You can use [Slack's channel redirect feature](https://api.slack.com/docs/deep-linking#app_channel) to create a link that will open any channel for a user. This also works with direct message channels by providing the ID of the target user.

Example for user `U12345678`:

```
https://slack.com/app_redirect?channel=U12345678
```

You can provide this link via Link button or text link.

Note that this will always open a new browser tab/window though, even if the user is using a Slack native client (and no, there is no way to find out if the user it using a native client or the browser).

Another approach would be to just provide the user-mention in your message and let the user click on it to get a menu which includes "Direct Messages". This will work with every user and on every platform / client type:

Just include a standard user mention in your text with some instructions to the user:

```
<@U12345678>
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that confirms (unfortunately) that I'm going to be stuck launching a web session for the user even if they are in the desktop app :( .  I'll try the feedback from you and Adil today and report back.  Maybe the @mention will work without looking too ugly.

Answer (score 4):

To create a link to a user's profile, try following the steps on [this page](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/360003827751-Create-a-link-to-a-member-s-profile-#free,-standard,-and-plus-plans-1):

> Create the link by combining your Workspace URL with members’ User IDs. Here’s how:
>
> The first part of the link is the Workspace URL. For example, https://acmeco.slack.com.
>       The second part of the link is the User ID. Multiple members' User IDs can be found using the `users.list` API method. Or, an individual's User ID can be found by clicking the  More actions icon in a member's profile, then choosing Copy member ID.
>       Append the User ID to the end of the Workspace URL. Here’s an example: https://acmeco.slack.com/team/U1H63D8SZ.

Using that same User ID, use the [`conversations.open`](https://slackapi.github.io/python-slackclient/conversations.html) API method to [create a DM/multi-person message with the target user](https://slackapi.github.io/python-slackclient/conversations.html):

```
from slackclient import SlackClient

slack_token = os.environ["SLACK_API_TOKEN"]
sc = SlackClient(slack_token)

sc.api_call(
  "conversations.open",
  users=["W1234567890","U2345678901","U3456789012"]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  The user profile link you suggested is exactly right, but the problem is if I reference the https:// ... in a message then the desktop Slack app will open a browser window (rather than just open the profile within the slack app).  The suggestion works fine if web only.

I'll dig into the second idea, multi-party chat is a great idea!